# Like '%c' not returning any rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table where each row is a word in the dictionary.

I have been using the following query to get all the words starting with a certain character (c):

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'c%'
```

That query works fine. But when i reverse it to get words ending in a character:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%c'
```

It doesn't return any rows.

What am I doing wrong? Ive checked for space padding on the right and that isn't the case.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have rows where the final character is `c`?

Comment: Are you sure your tables contain data in the `words` column that end in a lowercase c, and is full-text searching on that column enabled??

Comment: I just put c there to represent any character. Ive really been trying with d and there are plenty of word in the table that end with d.

Comment: @michael the column is a varchar

Comment: example data please. can you provide it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: x2 on the example data. I just ran the query on my local installation and it performed fine with '%s', and was case insensitive.

Comment: @PenguinCoder: full-text is _useless_ when searching for words _ending_ in anything. @Deekor: a good inspection of a variable you _think_ should match is running it through `HEX`. If it doesn't show anything weird, show use the normal value & `HEX` output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when i added the words the the table "\r\n" was added to the end of each word. I discovered this when exporting the data to show Juergen D.

Thanks for your help guys.